# C# wpf Live charts how to Autoadapt axis in terms of values and labels with code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, label, axis, livecharts

I have a project that has to be developed in WPF and code behind only with Live charts. The idea is to have a temperature graph.
Below you can see what I have already been doing by adding values to the lineSerie. I start by adding values to the line serie and when more than 120 I remove the first one:

```
lineSerie1_Part.Values.Add(new ObservableValue((double)val));
if (lineSerie1_Part.Values.Count >= 120)
        lineSerie1_Part.Values.RemoveAt(0);
```

[image]

Now I have two problems:

---

1. I would like not to have on the X axis the number of added values but the time when the temperature has been taken (e.g. 10:03:24 - 10:04:18 - ...). I have therefore written a small test program in which I set the labels:

   ```
   Labels = new[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC"};
   cc.AxisX[0].Labels = Labels;
   ```

and that works. That said I can't change it:

```
Labels[0] = "DDD";
Labels[1] = "EEE";
Labels[2] = "FFF";      
cc.AxisX[0].Labels = Labels;
```

does not make any change. **Additionally, is that the right way to do it? Would there be a way that when I add a new value, that value already has in it its x axis label?**

---

2. I may set the max and min temperature at the beginning (e.g. 18°-25°),

   ```
   chartTemperatures.AxisY.Add(new Axis { MinValue = MinTemp, MaxValue = MaxTemp);
   ```

but I would like the graphic to automatically extend if the temperature exceeds the initial values (e.g. 25.5°).

Thanks for any help
Patrick

Comment: cc.AxisX[0].Label[0] = "DDD";cc.AxisX[0].Label[1] = "EEE";cc.AxisX[0].Label[2] = "FFF";

Comment: As I said above I already am doing it but it doesn't make any change. So perhaps I don't know how to update it.

Comment: You are not doing that.  You are creating a new array and trying to replace the old array with the new array.  I'm actually changing the values of the existing array.

Comment: Actually I tried your code (labels not lable btw) cc.AxisX[0].Labels[0] = "DDD"; cc.AxisX[0].Labels[1] = "EEE"; cc.AxisX[0].Labels[2] = "FFF"; on a button click event but got no change however. That said, isn't there a better way to do it? Can't I add the new value with ALREADY the label?

Comment: No better method.  You have to change existing array but can enumerate through array.  If it accepted the value (not error) then it indicates the control did not repaint so you aren't seeing the change even though the value has changed.

Comment: Thanks that lead me to the solution! I just have to add a new value and it magically work! Any idea for the other problem?

Comment: Auto Scaling will not work.  You need to manually set min and max.   The only other solution is to set min and max to worse case values (like -40 to + 100) but then you will get less resolution.

Comment: That is enough for me. You might want to post that as a solution so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Jdweng there is not automatic method. So I have to use cc.AxisX[0].Label[0] = "DDD";cc.AxisX[0].Label[1] = "EEE";cc.AxisX[0].Label[2] = "FFF"